# Run a jquery script on on a certain template page

Tags: functions, jquery, javascript, templates, wp-enqueue-script

All I want to do is basically this:

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery_zebra', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/library/scripts/jquery.zebra.js', array('jquery'));    
wp_register_style( 'css_zebra', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/library/styles/zebra.css' );
//enqueue scripts
wp_enqueue_script('jquery_zebra');
wp_enqueue_style('css_zebra');
```

But only on a certain template page.  I don't care if this is in a plugin or my functions.php or in the template-page.php iteself.

Comment: How much do you know about Themes and PHP?

Answer (score 2):

There is [`is_page_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) conditional tag to check for that.